# what's the use of string.Clone()?

Tags: c#, .net, string, .net-2.0

there are 2  examples of code:
 # 1

```
 string str1 = "hello";
 string str2 = str1; //reference to the same string
 str1 = "bye"; //new string created
```

and # 2

```
string str3 = "hello";
string str4 = (string)str3.Clone();//reference to the same string
str3 = "bye";//new string created
```

looks like they are identical aren't they? so what is the benefit to use Clone()? can you give me an example when I cannot use code#1 but code#2 ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is useful since string implements *ICloneable*, so you can create a copy of clones for a collection of *ICloneable* items. This is boring when the collection is of strings only, but it's useful when the collection contains multiple types that implement *ICloneable*.

As for copying a single string it has no use, since it returns by design a reference to itself.

Comment: But why may I need the copy of a collection of IClonable objects? How to use that collection further, other than creating one more copy =) ? It's the same as a collection of "System.Object" - it's an impasse.

Answer (score 21):

Not directly in answer to your question, but in case you are looking to actually clone a string, you can use the static `string.Copy()` method.

Comment: In no case should you use string.Copy.  See remarks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.copy?view=net-5.0#remarks  `However, we do not recommend its use in any .NET implementation.`

Answer (score 3):

.Clone() in the above code is the same as the simple assignment. Also, string is immutable, so it will copy on write in both cases.

.Clone() would be a lot more useful in cases, where you are using different types, that implement the same interface (in this case IClonable) as you would not be able to use a simple assignment, but could still cast the object returned by Clone() to ICloneable and assign that reference. For instance iterating through a generic collection with ICloneable elements.