# String.Clone() what is it's purpose?

Tags: c#, .net, string

From [`String.Clone()` on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.clone.aspx):

> The return value is not an independent copy of this instance; it is
> simply another view of the same data. Use the Copy or CopyTo method to
> create a separate String object with the same value as this instance.
>
> Because the Clone method simply returns the existing string instance,
> **there is little reason to call it directly**.

It is my understanding that String is a *reference type* meaning that you will only ever get a reference to the string object when calling a string.

Therefore why does String.Clone() exist?  What is it's purpose?

Comment: You're right, `string` is a reference type, but it is also immutable, so it acts a little bit different than any other reference type. However, it doesn't change the fact, that `Clone` method is nor really useful.

Comment: Because `string.SubString(0)` does not return a copy, but the same reference passed to it, unintuitively.

Answer (score 2):

> This is useful since string implements ICloneable, so you can create a
>   copy of clones for a   collection of ICloneable items. This is boring
>   when the collection is of strings only,  but it's useful when the
>   collection contains multiple types that implement ICloneable.      As
>   for copying a single string it has no use, since it returns by design
>   a reference to itself.

Refer : [what's the use of string.Clone()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465377/whats-the-use-of-string-clone)

> The Clone() method returns a reference to the string which is being cloned. 
>   It is not an independent copy of the string on the **Heap**. It is another reference 
>   on the same string.

and read this article : [Explanation for Clone with examples](http://www.dotnetperls.com/clone)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just to implement the `ICloneable` interface. Please see [ICloneable.Clone Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.clone.aspx).

Furthermore, the `ICloneable` interface seems to be obsolete:

- [Implementing ICloneable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2003/04/09/49935.aspx)
- [Should we Obsolete ICloneable (The SLAR on System.ICloneable)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2004/05/03/125427.aspx)